# symfony2 cache clear --env=prod not printing anything

Tags: symfony, console, production-environment

When I run, as I usually do `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`, nothing happens, no message is printed, no error.

Things work fine for `--env=dev`.

Same goes for `assetic:dump`.

I'm a bit lost concerning how to troubleshoot this. Does anyone know?

Comment: maybe try to hard clean cache (like rm app/cache/* -rf) then run again the command

Comment: Yup. This is a strange issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a Fatal error that you can't see you can try to run your command with specific log-path and then see at your log file where was a problem.

```
php -derror_log=php.log app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

This command will run your script and redirect all errors to the `php.log` file located at the current working dir. Make sure that you have enough privileges to create file at this path. You can test it by running command `touch php.log`

Comment: I don't have the problem anymore now. Will definitely try this next time it happens.

Comment: I think that you should rewrite your question. Because "right" answer solve your problem but don't answer your question. It can confuse other people that want to know how to see errors while in console.

Comment: But at the same time, I'm not sure it does solve the issue as long as I don't try it. If what happened happens again, I'll definitely ammend some changes here (I'll need to come here to check your answer details anyway!)

Comment: I think in that case you can create another question and answer it by self with my answer. Your current question is about absence of any information in console. But the answer is about how to do things that you tried to do another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hard clean cache (like rm app/cache/* -rf) then run again the command